# d3: how to move a vertical line in horizontal direction and support 'pause' and 'continue' movement

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to move a vertical line in horizontal direction, and support 'pause' and 'continue' movement. When I click 'pause' button, the line stops moving; and when 'continue', the line continue moving.

Now, I use 'transition' function to implement horizontal transition from left to right, but don't know how to 'pause' and 'continue'.

Here is my demo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="500" height="500">
    <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="black"/>
  </svg>
</body>

<script>
  d3.select("line").transition()
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("x1",200)
    .attr("x2",200);
</script>
</html>
```

Is it possible to 'pause' the transition or how to use other ways to achieve this goal without using 'transition' function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do that:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="control-buttons">
    <button class="pause">
      Pause
    </button>
    <button class="continue">
      Continue
    </button>    
  </div>
  <svg width="1000" height="500">
    <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="100" stroke="black"/>
  </svg>
</body>

<script>   
  // pause
  d3.select('button.pause').on('click', function() {
   d3.select("line").interrupt();
  });
  
  d3.select('button.continue').on('click', function() {
   d3.select("line").transition()
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .duration(10000)
      .attr("x1",800)
      .attr("x2",800);
  }).dispatch('click');
  
</script>
</html>
```

[d3-transition-interrupt](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#selection_interrupt) is what you should be looking for. I've used it for the **pause** button and **continue** button click just has the same transition re-enabled. To start the transition, a click on the continue button is dispatched.

This is just a basic version but I hope the logic is clear enough. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps. Can you explain the function 'dispatch'? I try the code and find if without 'dispatch' it will not start at first. So dispatch is something about this. But I still can't really know what dispatch did after searching in document.

Comment: [dispatch](https://github.com/d3/d3-dispatch) is just triggering the "continue" button's click event on page load. If you observe, I moved all of your transition code within the "click" event.